# How do I get the latest post in the selected language with qTranslate-x?

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate-x

The setting in the settings=>languages for "Hide Content which is not available for the selected language." is **unchecked**. This is the preferred state for the whole site, but for some posts I would like to show only the latest post in the selected language. (So without the default behavior: "Sorry, this entry is only available in French.").

So far I have this code, which shows the latest post in the language it is written in, but I would like to get only the posts written in the selected language.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$mypost = get_post(get_the_ID()); 
$content = qtranxf_use('en', $mypost->post_content,false); 
echo "$content";
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I've used this approach to query on a specific language:

```
$mypost = array('post_type' => 'posts', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 's' => '[:en]',  'posts_per_page' => 7);
```

It adds an extra [query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for the keyword: [:en] or any language you want. And than you can just loop through it:

```
$loop = new WP_Query($mypost);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <article>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>
<?php
endwhile;
```